# UITableViewCell being reused while still on-screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have what probably seems like a really weird problem (it does to me!)

I am using a `UITableView` to display cells which each contain a `UIWebView`. I realise that this is a bad idea on the face of it, but I can't really do this any other way.

I am caching the heights of each cell when the `UIWebView` finishes loading, and then calling:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

**All of the germane code is [in a Gist here](https://gist.github.com/obeattie/da12ae2b65fb7c87dc8d).**

I also have the `UIWebView`s cached in a dictionary on the data source, so it can be reused when the cell is reloaded.

This seems to sort of work, but I am encountering a lot of issues whereby the cells' contents will randomly disappear. I have added some logging into determine what's going on, and in what order, and it seems like some of the cells are being reused *while they're still on-screen*.

I see this in my logs while scrolling down:

```
2014-02-11 13:45:49.091 EApp[45936:70b] Generating cell for 1: Panning
2014-02-11 13:45:49.245 EApp[45936:70b] Generating cell for 2: Calibration
2014-02-11 13:45:50.063 EApp[45936:70b] Generating cell for 3: Aperture Priority
2014-02-11 13:45:50.063 EApp[45936:70b] Reusing cell: Stopping down
```

"Stopping down" in this case is a cell that is still on-screen. The "generating cell" items are logged inside the data source's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the "reusing" messages inside the cells' `prepareForReuse`.

Does anyone know what could be happening here? I know this seems complex.

Comment: "I am encountering a lot of issues whereby the cells' contents will randomly disappear." That's the real problem then. Most of the time, the culprit is in your `table:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - seeing its code would greatly simplify figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: why are you reloading some cell exactly ? (for what purpose ?)

Comment: It sounds like you're adding a child view (probably your UIWebView) to a different cell, which removes it from the one it was in to start with.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Here is the code from both the data source's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and the cells' `prepareForReuse` methods: https://gist.github.com/obeattie/da12ae2b65fb7c87dc8d

Comment: @AncAinu Here, I am not reloading it (though my table view controller does reload the cell when the web view finishes loading). The problem I am describing is while scrolling though: the cells are reused even though they are still on-screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in your `prepareForReuse` is probably the culprit:

```
if ([self.contentWebView isDescendantOfView:self.contentWebView]) {
    [self.contentWebView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

As the `contentWebView` is never a descendant of itself, it will not be removed from the cell, and the contentView will contain ***two*** webviews after the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

You probably meant to say:

```
if ([self.contentWebView isDescendantOfView:self.contentView]) {
    [self.contentWebView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Or simply:

```
[self.contentWebView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: You sir, are a saint.

Answer (score 0):

One of the features/limitations of UITableView is that you don't know if, and can't depend on, a cell is being created or reused. You should always be able to handle both.

*GENERALLY*, when you call `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, you will get the cell from that indexPath to reuse. If that indexPath was on screen, it will be a cell that was on screen.

Comment: The problem I'm encountering though is more to do with scrolling: the cells that are still on-screen are reused to make new ones while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the problem, but in the code you provided, you don't even initialize your cell...

I'm even surprise it works.

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedItemCell";
 EFeedItemCell *cell = [self.tableViewController.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

you should add to it :

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [EfeedItemCell alloc] initWithReus....];
}
```

Comment: I've added that in (and updated the Gist) but it doesn't seem to do anything. I added a breakpoint to the code inside the if statement too, and it seems it is never called. Thanks though!

If it makes a difference, the cells are laid out (with the exception of the `UIWebView`) in a `.storyboard` file.

Comment: So your table is fed from somewhere else... dequeueReusableCell gather existing cell from the table. And existing cells come from somewhere.
What I mean it's if you never write [[EFeedItemCell alloc] init] then your cells are like Jesus, born from nowhere. And for Jesus I don't know, but for your cells it can't be.
But in the end if you don't even know where your cells are created, so sure you can have problems.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems that you are caching the webViews and then are adding them to cells programmatically. This can create random problems similar to what I had faced in the passed.

You must use **`EFeedItemCellWebView`** in your storyboard. Just add a `UIWebView` and change the class name to your custom class. And then when the data is loaded just simply change its contents in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Comment: make sure to create IBOutlet connection to the custom UIWebview.

Comment: Are you proposing that I:

1. Add the `EFeedItemCellWebView` to my `.storyboard` file
2. Create *another* `EFeedItemCellWebView` inside the table view data source
3. Swap one for the other in the data source, once the (data source-created) one has finished loading?

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: No! don't create another 'EFeedItemCellWebView'. Just change the contents of 'EFeedItemCellWebView' in the cell when you reload them. I had faced similar problems when I saved views in array and was using them in UITableViewCells. You also don't need to cache the heights. calculate them at runtime unless if they are making the app too slow.

Comment: The reason I did not want to do this is that I'd like to avoid reloading the web views each and every time the user scrolls up/down. Also, the heights of the web views will not change after they have finished loading, so it seemed silly to *not* cache the heights; the calculation involves Javascript execution so obviously less is more in this regard.